# How to make a realtime chart with Highcharts, Firebase, ReactJS with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, highcharts, real-time

I need to create a graph in real time getting data from Firebase. I'm using ReactJs with typescript along with Highcharts.
I've already managed to simulate Highcharts in real time, but now I'm wondering how I can connect it to get the data that will be added to Firebase.

Global Graph Component:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import HighchartsAccessibility from 'highcharts/modules/accessibility';
import HighchartsData from 'highcharts/modules/data';
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import HighchartsHeatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
import HighchartsTreeChart from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';

import { defaultTheme } from '../../../styles/themes';

HighchartsAccessibility(Highcharts);
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsData(Highcharts);
HighchartsHeatmap(Highcharts);
HighchartsTreeChart(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

interface IChartProps {
    options: Highcharts.Options;
}

export const labelsStyle = (
    fontSize = 20,
    color = defaultTheme.palette.grey[900]
) => ({
    color,
    fontSize: `${fontSize / 16}rem`,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    margin: '0px',
    fontWeight: 400,
    lineHeight: `${(fontSize + 10) / 16}rem`,
});

export const Chart: React.FC<IChartProps> = ({ options }) => {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        // rangeSelector: {
        //  enabled: false,
        // },
        // navigator: {
        //  enabled: false,
        // },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                style: labelsStyle(),
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                style: labelsStyle(18, defaultTheme.palette.grey[200]),
            },
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
        },
    });

    return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};
```

Realtime Graph Component:

```
import { TooltipFormatterContextObject } from 'highcharts';
import {
    Chart,
    labelsStyle,
} from '../../../../shared/components/DataDisplay/Chart';
import { defaultTheme } from '../../../../shared/styles/themes';
import { formatDate } from '../../../../shared/utils/date';
import { getRandomIntInclusive } from '../../../../shared/utils/math';

export const GraphHeartRateMonitor: React.FC = () => {
    const analyticsDataState = {
        dates: [],
        data: [],
    };

    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            height: '176px',
            plotBackgroundColor: defaultTheme.palette.background.default,
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load() {
                    const series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        const x = new Date().getTime(), // current time
                            y = getRandomIntInclusive(80, 120);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                },
            },
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 300,
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '',
            },
            gridLineColor: defaultTheme.palette.background.default,
            tickInterval: 10,
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            plotLines: [
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: defaultTheme.palette.red[300],
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: '120',
                        useHTML: true,
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        align: 'left',
                        style: {
                            background: defaultTheme.palette.red[300],
                            borderRadius: '24px',
                            height: '18px',
                            padding: '2px 12px',
                            color: defaultTheme.palette.common.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto Mono',
                            fontSize: '12px',
                            fontWeight: '400',
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            // lineColor: defaultTheme.palette.background.default,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Random data',
                color: defaultTheme.palette.grey[900],
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    let data = [],
                        time = new Date().getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: getRandomIntInclusive(80, 120),
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })(),
            },
        ],
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: defaultTheme.palette.background.paper,
            borderRadius: 4,
            shadow: {
                color: defaultTheme.palette.common.black,
            },
            padding: 12,
            style: labelsStyle(20, defaultTheme.palette.grey[300]),
            formatter() {
                const self: TooltipFormatterContextObject = this;

                return `
          <span> Time:</span>
          <strong>${formatDate(new Date(self.x), 'HH:mm:ss')}</strong>

          </br>
          <span>Heart Rate:</span>
          <strong >${self.y} bpm</strong>
        `;
            },
        },
    };
    return <Chart options={options} />;
};
```

To call the component just call as a normal component `<GraphHeartRateMonitor />` .

Comment: Hi @Jecé Xavier, First of all, you should place the chart options and `Highcharts.setOptions` call outside of the components. As to the dynamic data, please add information about its structure (will it be the same for the first and every next call?).

Comment: Welcome to SO. I may be overlooking it but I don't see any Firebase code in the question or any attempt to read that data. Are you asking us to write the code for you? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)